# How to stop ASP.NET from changing IDs in order to use jQuery

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax

I have this label control in my web page

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="test"></asp:Label>
```

And when the page rendered the id of the control changes to something like this

```
  <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Label3">test</span>
```

How can I stop asp.net from changing IDs in order to perform a jQuery operation like this

```
$('#label1').html(xml);
```

Comment: Other answers have already shown various work-arounds for the fact that ASP.Net annoyingly insists on creating its own client IDs. Though it doesn't help with your immediate issue I recently read that this will be one of the features in ASP.Net 4.0 later this year. Thought you may be interested.

Comment: FYI, this is coming in ASP.NET 4.0 (the ability to control client-side IDs of server controls)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

instead of using this selector

```
$('#Label1')
```

use this one, basically you are using the classic asp inline server side code.

```
$('#<%= Label1.ClientID %>')
```

this will insert whatever ID that is generated to be placed as a literal.

If you wish to use external files then I would suggest you create an obj that is global on the page to hold all of your client ids and then reference that obj within your external files (not ideal but it is a solution)

```
var MyClientIDs = {
    Label1 = '<%= Label1.ClientID %>',
    Label2 = '<%= Label2.ClientID %>',
    Textbox1 = '<%= Textbox1.ClientID %>',
    Textbox2 = '<%= Textbox2.ClientID %>'
};
```

and then in your external file you can access Label1 for example: `$('#' + MyClientIDs.Label1)`

Comment: Problem with that is that it cannot be used in an external javascript file

Comment: Dreas: function getLabel1Id() { return '#<%= Label1.ClientID %>'; } - if you put that in the aspx file, you can call it from your js files.

Comment: sorry - i find this a poor solution since it discourages the use of external js files, which is best practice.

Comment: It's got another gotcha - once you put that server tag into your page you'll get an exception if you try to add dynamic controls.

Comment: @Triptych I agree... one way around it is to create a global object that is on the page that will give you access to all of the client ids. I'll update the answer with an example

Comment: With asp.net 4.0 @user2622042 's answer below is the easiest and cleanest (unless you are in a repeater or similar) https://stackoverflow.com/a/19109742/661584 here is a good reference https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2009/Nov/07/ClientIDMode-in-ASPNET-40

Answer (score 52):

#### Short answer:

Set `ClientIDMode="Static"`

```
<asp:Label ID="myLabel" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Text="testing"></asp:Label>
```

---

#### Long answer:

.NET 4 now has the ability to let you choose your [ClientIDMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx):

Type: [System.Web.UI.ClientIDMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientidmode.aspx) 
A value that indicates how the ClientID property is generated.

> **AutoID** 
> The ClientID value is generated by concatenating the ID values
> of each parent naming container with the ID value of the control. In
> data-binding scenarios where multiple instances of a control are
> rendered, an incrementing value is inserted in front of the control's
> ID value. Each segment is separated by an underscore character (_).
> This algorithm was used in versions of ASP.NET earlier than ASP.NET 4.
>
> **Static** 
>  The ClientID value is set to the value of the ID property. If
> the control is a naming container, the control is used as the top of
> the hierarchy of naming containers for any controls that it contains.
>
> **Predictable**  
>  This algorithm is used for controls that are in data-bound
> controls. The ClientID value is generated by concatenating the
> ClientID value of the parent naming container with the ID value of the
> control. If the control is a data-bound control that generates
> multiple rows, the value of the data field specified in the
> ClientIDRowSuffix property is added at the end. For the GridView
> control, multiple data fields can be specified. If the
> ClientIDRowSuffix property is blank, a sequential number is added at
> the end instead of a data-field value. This number begins at zero and
> is incremented by 1 for each row. Each segment is separated by an
> underscore character (_).
>
> **Inherit** 
>  The control inherits the ClientIDMode setting of its NamingContainer control. This is the default.

Comment: IN OTHER WORDS, use static mode to force ASP not to change the id

Comment: This is the best answer

Answer (score 27):

In .NET 4+ set `ClientIDMode="Static"`. This will solve your problem.

Example:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Text="test"></asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 20):

You can't stop asp.net from generating those IDs. That's just how it does things.

You can still use jquery like so:

```
$('#<%=label1.ClientID %>').html(xml)
```

or

```
$('[id$=_label1]').html(xml)
```

Comment: In .NET 4 you can stop asp.net from generating those IDS: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8428188/40961 with the ClientIDMode value.

Answer (score 17):

**If** and **only if** you're container layout is never going to change **and** you require to put your JavaSctipt/jQuery in an external file, you could use the generated ids within your jQuery selectors i.e.

```
$('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Label3').html(xml);
```

Obviously, this approach requires you to find out what the generated ids will be and requires caution if you ever start changing the site/application construction.

Otherwise, your *best* options are

**1.** Use the inline server side code markup. The downside to this approach is that you cannot put your js code in an external file -

```
$('#<%= Label3.ClientID %>').html(xml);
```

**2.** Define unique CSS classes on each control you need to use in your jQuery, which would still allow you to put your js code in an external file -

```
<asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="test" CssClass="label3">
</asp:Label>

$('.label3').html(xml);
```

**3.** Use jQuery selectors to pattern match the original id, which again, would allow you to put your js code in an external file -

```
$('[id$=Label3]').html(xml);
```

This jQuery selector will select all elements with attribute *id* whose value ends with *Label3*. The only potential downside that I could see with this approach is that in theory, it could be possible to have a Label control with id Label3 in say, a Master page and also in two content pages. In this example, using the jQuery selector above would match all three labels, which may have unwanted consequences.

**EDIT:**

I thought it might be useful to raise your attention to the [IDOverride control](http://www.wilcob.com/Wilco/News/AspNetIDOverride.aspx). An [Example page can be found here](http://www.wilcob.com/Demos/IDOverride/)

It allows you to specify which controls should have their mangled id within the outputted HTML markup overridden with the id as is given in the .aspx file when rendering out the HTML page. I have only played with it briefly with a single Master Page and Panels, but it appears to work well. Using this, you could use the original ids within your jQuery selectors. Be aware however, that the results are unpredictable if you were to have controls with the same ids in your Master page(s) and Content page(s) that are combined to render the HTML for one page.

Comment: Very nice answer.  I think using jQuery makes things like placeholders obsolete, but you answered the actual question completely and authoritatively!

Comment: The pages for IDOverride appear to be gone.  I've hunted around the net and I can't find it.  Anyone have a copy posted anywhere?  I've got a simple site that could really benefit from it and I'm not in a position to wait until ASP.Net 4.0 or to learn MVC at the moment.

Answer (score 7):

Short answer, don't worry about using the asp.net IDs. In asp.net you can add your own attribute to a tag:

```
<asp:TexBox ID="myTBox" runat="server" MyCustomAttr="foo" />
```

Then in jquery you can refer to this element via:

```
$("input[MyCustomAttr='foo']")
```

I do this all the time with jQuery. Hope it helps.

Comment: it is valid html5 if you prefix your custom attributes with `data-`

Answer (score 7):

You can call a class name rather than using an ID

For example;

```
$('.CssClassName'). ...
```

Or if you type this in the MasterPage's very first line, your control IDs won't change :

`ClientIDMode="Static"`

For example;

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="Main_MasterPage" ClientIDMode="Static" %>
```

Answer (score 5):

The inline code is the correct way to do it.  However this will be changing in ASP.NET 4.0. We have spent some time adding a feature that allows full control of the IDs that are generated client side. Below are some resources on the web about this feature.

- http://blog.osbornm.com/archive/2009/01/06/asp.net-4.0-clientid-overview-again.aspx
- http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/10-4/10-4-Episode-3-ASPNET-WebForms-40/

Answer (score 4):

Most of the suggestions here will work, but test results on jQuery code show that pure ID selectors are by far the fastest. The one I use most often:

```
$("[id$=origControlId]")
```

is pretty slow, but the problem isn't too apparent unless the page has many controls and a lot of jQuery.

Since is it fairly painless to assign multiple classes to a control, you could give each one a CSSClass that matches the ID. Since they would then be unique (you'll have to watch repeater type controls that generate multiple controls), you could select by class.

For example:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" CssClass="Label1 SomeOtherClass" runat="server" Text="test">
</asp:Label>
```

could be selected uniquely by:

```
$(".Label1")
```

Which is *almost* as fast as an ID select.

I had never considered this one:

```
$('#<%= Label1.ClientID %>')
```

but I'm going to try it!

Answer (score 3):

You have to pass the control's ClientID to the javascript code (I doubt though that Label1 gets renamed to Label3)

```
ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "someKey", 
    "$('#" + Label1.ClientID + "').html(xml);", true);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `ClientID` (just like everyone else said) but the problem with that is that it cannot be used in an external JavaScript File.

So, ideally, instead of using the ID to reference it from jQuery, **use a CSS class**:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="test" CssClass="myclass"></asp:Label>
```

Then you can reference it like such:

```
$(".myclass")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can override the ClientID and the UniqueID as [this fella did](http://www.west-wind.com/WebLog/posts/4605.aspx).

```
/// <summary>
/// Override to force simple IDs all around
/// </summary>

public override string UniqueID
{
    get
    {
        return this.ID;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Override to force simple IDs all around
/// </summary>

public override string ClientID
{
    get
    {
        return this.ID;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a good idea.  If you have a complex control and one of the nested controls is doing this.  You could easily result with multiple controls on the page with a common ID, which is not what you desire.

Answer (score 2):

You may also create a custom control that inherits from Label that overrides the ID property to be what you want it to be.

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved by replacing the asp.net id with the original id as the control is rendered.
This is pretty easy and can be donw by creating a set of custom controls.

http://www.bytechaser.com/en/articles/ts8t6k5psp/how-to-display-aspnet-controls-with-clean-id-value.aspx

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of being patently obvious change:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="test"></asp:Label>
```

to

```
<Label ID="Label1" Text="test"></Label>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the property `ClientIDMode="Static"` in your button, this grants the ID will be the same in runtime, it's what you need to get object in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to "prevent" asp.net from changing the control id in order to use jquery, or javascript at all for that matter.

the id that gets rendered on your page is the ClientID property of the control and what you're setting on the control itself is the ID.  you can't set the ClientID property, it's generated for you and may or may not be the same as your ID.  however, as others have mentioned you can use the ClientID property either in your aspx:

```
$('<%= Label1.ClientID %>').html()
```

or by registering the client script in your code behind file using one of the ClientScriptManager methods.

Answer (score 0):

Just get rid of the placeholder.  Or select by class or DOM hierarchy.  Or even use partial matching on the ID as a last resort.  There are many easy, clean ways to select an element in jQuery, we need to wean ourselves away from our old, ugly ASP.NET habits.

And Dreas Grech put the final nail in the coffin.  You can't use use external script files with the $('#<%=label1.ClientID %>') type solutions.

Mike

Answer (score 0):

You still can use PlaceHolders and set **ClientIDMode** in the PlaceHolder tag :

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">        
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

None of the contained controls IDs will be altered.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, with overriding the control class. Here is an example with an HtmlGenericControl but you can do it with any ASP.Net control:

```
public class NoNamingContainerControl : HtmlGenericControl
{
    public NoNamingContainerControl(string tag) : base(tag) { }
    public override string ClientID
    {
        get
        {
            return this.ID;
        }
    }
}
```