# jquery and asp.net textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

"What I am trying to achieve is onclick will remove the text within a textbox".

I read some answers from this [site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716827/jquery-click-event-on-aspbutton) which someone is using "function pageLoad(sender, args)" javascript but the problem is that on debug using Firefox break point the function line doesn't stop on it. Am I missing a loaded up javascript requirement from microsoft or something else? here is my test code.

```
    function pageLoad() {
        $("#<%=Text_Message.ClientID%>").click(function () {
            alert("Handler for .click() called.");
        });
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%=Text_Message.ClientID%>").click(function () {
            alert("Handler for .click() called.");
        });
    });
```

textbox

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Text_Name" runat="server" CssClass="" Width="234px" >Name</asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: For one, it should be `<%=Text_Name.ClientID%>` based on your example

Comment: Why don't you use classes? It will be much easier !!! http://jsfiddle.net/3Pg8F/

Comment: I am still learning server side html and normal html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [`focus`](http://api.jquery.com/focus/) instead of click on textbox and empty its text using `$(this).val("");`

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/LVQNs/)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%=Text_Message.ClientID%>").focus(function () {
            alert("Handler for .click() called.");
            $(this).val("");
        });
 });
```