# ASP.NET Webforms and Jquery - strategy for dealing with ID mangling

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I like jQuery and am using ASP.NET. I know you can get round ID mashing a bit using the ClientID but this dosn't work well when are farming you script out to sepearte js files.

The only way I have used round this is to store the ClientID in a javascript variable on the page then use this id in the seperate js file. But this is less than ideal.

Does anyone have any better ways of dealing with this (other than wait for ASP.NET 4.0!)

**EDIT: Duplicate Question:**

[How to stop ASP.NET from changing IDs in order to use jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497802/how-to-stop-asp-net-from-changing-ids-in-order-to-use-jquery/498972#498972)

Answer (score 1):

I use class names for selecting stuff with jQuery when I'm working with nested web controls.. together with id's on controls which are not nested.