# Checkbox and JQUERY: "is checked" always FALSE

Tags: jquery, checkbox

The code is below and checkbox is always FALSE. But on page it is different. It doesn't get checked or unchecked.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('.cbOzelHastaAdi').unbind('click');

 $('.cbOzelHastaAdi').click( function() {

    var parentDiv = $(this).parent().get(0);
    var cbs = $(parentDiv).find('table input:checkbox');

   if($(this).attr("checked") === "true") {
        cbs.each(function() { $(this).attr('checked', false); });
    }
    else{
        cbs.each(function() { $(this).attr('checked', true); });
    }

})

</script>
```

Comment: can you reformat this?  It is really hard to read.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

One of the problems was that you had the `checked` attribute on the span surrounding the top checkbox and label and were binding an event handler to the span, therefore `checked` will always remain `checked` on the span.

I have moved the event handlers to the checkbox instead and tidied up the code a bit. Whilst I don't believe there is a problem in constructing your own attributes on HTML elements i.e. a checked attribute on a span element (I think XHTML strict validation fails with them), I don't whether it's considered good practice to do so.

I can see that you are using ASP.NET, based on the ID mangling - you can use server side `<%= myControl.ClientID %>` to get the mangled id to render in the HTML sent to the client.

[Working Example here](http://jsbin.com/opuza)

```
   $(function() {     
        $('#rptOzel_ctl00_rptOzelHastalar_ctl00_cbOzelKurumHastasi').unbind('click');
        $('#rptOzel_ctl00_rptOzelHastalar_ctl00_cbOzelKurumHastasi').click( function() {

           var cbs = $('table input:checkbox');  

           if($(this).is(':checked')){
               cbs.each(function() { $(this).attr('checked', true); });
           }
           else{
            cbs.each(function() { $(this).attr('checked', false); });
           }

        });
    });
```

**EDIT:**

In response to your comment, you have a couple of options for resolving the clientid. If you write your jQuery in the aspx page, then you can simply use

`$('#<%= cbOzelKurumHastasi.ClientID %>')`

in place of

`$('#rptOzel_ctl00_rptOzelHastalar_ctl00_cbOzelKurumHastasi')`

If you have your jQuery in an external script file then you could put this in your aspx page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var cbOzelKurumHastasi = '#<%= cbOzelKurumHastasi.ClientID %>';
</script>
```

and then use the variable in your external script file

```
$(function() {     
            $(cbOzelKurumHastasi).unbind('click');
            $(cbOzelKurumHastasi).click( function() { ...
```

For other options take a look at this question and answer - [How to stop ASP.NET from changing ids in order to use jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497802/how-to-stop-asp-net-from-changing-ids-in-order-to-use-jquery/498972#498972)

Comment: would you please write the code on server. I couldn't get how to bind with clientID.
And do you know how to bind with cssclass attr.?

Comment: In this repeater, I referenced the changing ID of the CheckBox with each iteration.  This has been added to the server-side code:    CheckBox cbHastaAdi = (CheckBox)e.Item.FindControl("cbOzelKurumHastasi");
    cbHastaAdi.Attributes["onclick"] = "javascript:isaretDegistir('" + cbHastaAdi.ClientID + "');";

and i could access to right element (without label) and its state (checked or not)

Thank you so much for your help. And of course to all of you. YOU ARE REALLY PERFECT PEOPLE.

Answer (score 7):

I usually us the .is() functionality of jQuery to check for this

```
$('.cbOzelHastaAdi').click( function() {
  if($(this).is(':checked')){
    ...
  }else{
    ...
  }
})
```

Comment: You are right. But it is always returning FALSE. The checkbox html value is : 
<input id="rptOzel_ctl00_rptOzelHastalar_ctl00_cbOzelKurumHastasi" name="rptOzel$ctl00$rptOzelHastalar$ctl00$cbOzelKurumHastasi" type="checkbox"><label for="rptOzel_ctl00_rptOzelHastalar_ctl00_cbOzelKurumHastasi">LÜTFİ OĞUZ</label>

Comment: @uzay95, it is because Corey Downie's code has a syntax error, should be `}else{`

Answer (score 3):

could it be because you are comparing the value of the checked property to a string rather than a boolean and using the === operator which compares both value and type?

Comment: Agreed. I would think that simply doing if($(this).attr('checked')) {} would work, mainly because I did it that way earlier today.

Comment: yes but i doesn't work. Because asp.net is not sending only input but also label. Thats why is(':checked') useless.

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same problem ones; checking whether a checkbox is checked ( in any of the different ways) always returned false.

My solution (course of problem) was in the JQuery selector that was used.

uzay95 used the class selector ".", to select its checkboxes.

$('.cbOzelHastaAdi')**

Which returns a result set. Therefor, checking if it is checked is invalid, because their might be multiple checkboxes... I know he's using the **this** keyword in his code, but for me this also did not fix the problem.

**As soon as you select the checkbox by ID, you can evaluate its 'checked' attribute.**

Answer (score 0):

I've found that the following is probably the best way to determine checked status in jQuery:

```
var cbs = $(parentDiv).find('table input:checkbox:checked');
```

This will give you an array of each input that has been checked.

This is mostly from the jQuery docs:

> [Selectors/Checked](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/checked)

Comment: this is good. But i couldn't get is the first cb is checked or not. There is problem about is('checked') .

Answer (score 0):

Russ Cam's answer works, but why not jQueryify it some more?

```
$(function() {     
    $('.cbOzelHastaAdi').live('click', function() {
        $(this).parents('div').find('table input:checkbox').attr('checked', $(this).attr('checked'));
    });
});
```

This assumes that the class *cbOzelHastaAdi* is now attached to the checkbox instead of the span element.  This should allow you to avoid all of the messy ASP renaming and allow multiple similar tables per page without the need for multiple click event functions.

Comment: @Ben - what your code would do is semantically different "all those checked make unchecked and all those unchecked make checked." What happens if you have some already checked/unchecked? you get the negative or reverse pattern! Also, the code doesn't work if you try it, you cannot check the top checkbox, I think becuase it will be picked up in the selector in the event handler

Comment: @Russ - you're right, I misunderstood what was trying to be accomplished here.  I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

=== is a type safe comparator for JS

See:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators

Answer (score 0):

This is also working:

```
(($('input[name="myCheckBox"]:checked').val())=='on')
```

It will return either true or false

where the checkbox is defined as:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="myCheckBox">
```