# jquery toggle() not working on content page

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am wondering why below code is not working. Could anybody of you help me, please?

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="Server">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#button").click(function () {
                $("#hide").toggle();
            });
        });
    </script>
    <asp:Button ID="button" runat="server" Text="button" OnClientClick="return false" />
    <div id="hide">
    <asp:Button ID="show" runat="server" Text="example" />
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

EDIT:
What in case when the button is in gridview or nested gridviev?
When I use
`$("#<%= button.ClientID %>")`
it returns me an error: "The name 'button' does not exist in the current context."
Will you be able to help me in that case?

Comment: Are you observing any error?

Comment: The id probably isn't `button` on the rendered page.

Comment: It's a div id; that isn't the problem. OP - what exactly do you mean by "not working"? What is or isn't happening?

Comment: I would agree with Jason ASP.net is changing your ID property.

Comment: Any ideas how can I reference to a nested control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is answered elsewhere:
[How to stop ASP.NET from changing IDs in order to use jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497802/how-to-stop-asp-net-from-changing-ids-in-order-to-use-jquery)

ASP.Net is not writing out the ID for the button as you would expect.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
$("#<%= button.ClientID %>").click(function () {
    $("#hide").toggle();
});
```

Comment: hide is not a server element.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$("#<%= button.ClientID %>").click(function () {
     $("#hide").toggle();
});
```