# Get value of hidden label in table using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an html table within a list view, and have a hidden label in it called "vehicle_num". I am able to get the selected row of the table, as well as any of the td, however I cannot seem to get the value of the label.  I have tried:

```
var vehicle_number = $(this).closest('tr').children('#vehicle_num').text();
```

Below is the code for the listview.  How can I get the value of the label?

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvEquipmentList" runat="server" DataKeyNames="vehicle_number">
    <LayoutTemplate>
            <table id="table-equipment-list" class="table table-list">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col" class="product-line">Product line</th>
                        <th scope="col" class="model-number">Model #</th>
                        <th scope="col" class="serial-number">Serial #</th>
                        <th scope="col" class="dar-status">DAR Status</th>
                        <th scope="col" class="ship-date">Ship Date</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="ItemPlaceholder" runat="server" /> 
                </tbody>
            </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" class="product-line"><div class="icon"><img src='<%#Eval("image_path")%>' onerror="this.src='assets/images/placeholder.png';" alt=""/></div> <span class="line-title"><%#Eval("product_line")%></span></th>
            <td class="model-number"><%#Eval("model")%><label class="vehicle_num" hidden="hidden"><%#Eval("vehicle_number")%></label></td>
            <td class="serial-number"><%#Eval("serial_number")%></td>
            <td class="dar-status"><img src='<%#Eval("display_status") %>'/></td>
            <td class="ship-date"><%#Eval("date")%></td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        <table id="table-equipment-list" class="table table-list">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col" class="product-line">Product line</th>
                    <th scope="col" class="model-number">Model #</th>
                    <th scope="col" class="serial-number">Serial #</th>
                    <th scope="col" class="dar-status">DAR Status</th>
                    <th scope="col" class="ship-date">Ship Date</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row" class="product-line"><div class="icon"></div> <span class="line-title"></span></th>
                    <td class="model-number"></td>
                    <td class="serial-number"></td>
                    <td class="dar-status"></td>
                    <td class="ship-date"></td>
                </tr>   
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

***EDIT***

I have edited the code above to put the label in a table column.  I was able to get the value using:

```
var vehicle_number = $(this).closest('tr').find('.vehicle_num').text();
```

Comment: `<label id="vehicle_num" hidden="hidden" runat="server">` - Either the client-side `id` isn't `vehicle_num` or there are multiple instances of the same client-side `id`.  The former means you need to change the selector, the latter is invalid and the behavior becomes undefined.  Also, the only valid children of a `tr` are `td` elements, so your markup is invalid anyway.

Comment: `ASP.NET` tends to change the `Control` `ID` specially when using `MasterPages`.

Comment: Check this out: [Control.ClientIDMode Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Related: [How to stop ASP.NET from changing IDs in order to use jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/497802/how-to-stop-asp-net-from-changing-ids-in-order-to-use-jquery)

Comment: Also fix your `HTML` markup as suggested by @David.

Comment: Thank you everyone, you were correct in that a label is not a valid child of a tr. Issue was solved by instead placing the hidden label in one of the columns.  I have edited my code above to include this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is invalid markup:

```
<tr>
    <th scope="row" class="product-line"><div class="icon"><img src='<%#Eval("image_path")%>' onerror="this.src='assets/images/placeholder.png';" alt=""/></div> <span class="line-title"><%#Eval("product_line")%></span></th>
    <td class="model-number"><%#Eval("model")%></td>
    <td class="serial-number"><%#Eval("serial_number")%></td>
    <td class="dar-status"><img src='<%#Eval("display_status") %>'/></td>
    <td class="ship-date"><%#Eval("date")%></td>
    <label id="vehicle_num" hidden="hidden" runat="server"><%#Eval("vehicle_number")%></label>
</tr>
```

There's an errant `label` as a child of a `tr`, which isn't valid.  When the browser tries to make sense of this, it could be doing anything with that `label` to construct a valid DOM, which is going to effect your jQuery selectors.

The `label` needs to be in a table cell:

```
<tr>
    <th scope="row" class="product-line"><div class="icon"><img src='<%#Eval("image_path")%>' onerror="this.src='assets/images/placeholder.png';" alt=""/></div> <span class="line-title"><%#Eval("product_line")%></span></th>
    <td class="model-number"><%#Eval("model")%></td>
    <td class="serial-number"><%#Eval("serial_number")%></td>
    <td class="dar-status"><img src='<%#Eval("display_status") %>'/></td>
    <td class="ship-date"><%#Eval("date")%></td>
    <td><label id="vehicle_num" hidden="hidden" runat="server"><%#Eval("vehicle_number")%></label></td>
</tr>
```

(Or, if it's always hidden anyway, you can probably put it in an existing table cell.  Either way should work.)

Additionally, if the client-side `id` is being explicitly set here, then any repetition of these records will result in duplicate `id`s in the DOM, which is also invalid.  Different browsers respond to `id`-based selectors in different ways when there are duplicate `id`s, because the behavior is undefined.  You probably want to use a class instead:

```
<label class="vehicle_num" ...
```

Since the `label` is no longer a *child* of the `tr` but rather a *descendant* of it, use `find()` instead of `children()`:

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('.vehicle_num')
```

Comment: Great suggestion, putting the label inside of one of the other td! I will try this now.

Comment: I have edited my code above to place the label inside a td. I was able to get the value by using: var vehicle_number = $(this).closest('tr').find('#vehicle_num').text();

Comment: @KateMak: I still recommend making sure you're not re-using the client-side `id`.  If that selector works then it means you are (provided there's more than one record in the `ListView`), which means that selector is *coincidentally* working in this particular case, but the markup remains invalid so there's no guarantee that it will always work or that other similar selectors will work.

Comment: Since this is a listview, the client side id would indeed be repeated...is there a better way I can achieve the desired result?

Comment: @KateMak: I imagine you could let ASP.NET manage the "id" and just use a "class" for the JavaScript selector.

Comment: Sounds good!  I will alter my code to use class instead.  Thank you again!