# javascript adds body_0$ to ID selector

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms

I am doing a form validation using  and the javascript works with just input fields but not Textboxes. I use:

```
 var _firstname;
 var box;

 try {
 box = $("#firstname");
 alert("You must enter a first name");
 box.focus();
 return false;
 }catch{
 }
```

with a front end of :

```
  <div>First Name <span class="required">*</span></div>
  <asp:TextBox ID="firstname" name="firstname" runat="server" />
```

When I debug the code, it adds a body_0$ to the front of the ID (ie: body_0$firstname), so I'm guessing that's why its always popping up with the "You must enter a first name" alert. Is there a work around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, JavaScript does not do that. It's the **ASP.NET WebForms runtime** that does it. the `ID` attribute you are providing is used by the server-side and is not output "as-is" to the client.

In its default mode, WebForms <del>mangles</del> *decorates* `id` attributes with the hierarchical structure of `runat="server"` element ids. This is good for WebForms, because you can reuse IDs in repeaters, panels and such without creating duplicate IDs on the client. However, it os not really good for anything else, like the browser or the struggling front-end developer.

This old question from 2009 might help:

[How to stop ASP.NET from changing IDs in order to use jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497802/how-to-stop-asp-net-from-changing-ids-in-order-to-use-jquery)

**Solution**

From ASP.NET 4.0, it is possible to select the `ClientIDMode`. Set it to `Predictable` or `Static` like this:

```
<%@Page Language="C#"
    CodeBehind="MyFormName.aspx.cs"
    Inherits="MyWebApplication.MyFormName"
    ClientIDMode="Static" 
%>
```

Just be careful NOT to do this when you are reusing or repeating server-side controls, as this would create multiple elements with the same client-side id! *(updated after [dman2306](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4508432/dman2306)'s comment)*

[Read more about `ClientIDMode` on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientidmode(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: so there is no way to translate an id on the front end to Javascript without ASP changing the ID?

Comment: There is a `ClientIDMode` setting on the `Page` object. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Be careful though, when you set it to static you need to ensure you don't have duplicates. If you have this control inside an `INamingContainer` such as a repeater or grid, you will end up with duplicate IDs and things will not work as you expect. This is why ASP.NET does what it does to your IDs so it ensures uniqueness.

Answer (score 1):

If your actual issue is not getting the ID's value, what about using this?

```
box = $("[id*=" + 'firstname' + "]").val();
```

it will look for any & all IDs containing the string 'firstname'

Although in your code it just runs through and shows the alert anyway. And your assignment to box is the control itself, not the value.

Comment: You don't have a conditional wrapper around the alert(). You assign to box, and then you call alert(). You need something like if (box === 'undefined') { alert(); }