# Javascript validation not working in ASP. Net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, validation

I am creating a registration form using html, css & javascript for validation and it's working great if I put **id="register-form"** in form tag.

```
<form method="post" role="form" autocomplete="off" id="register-form">
```

IMG of validation https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oya5L.jpg

but as i also want `<asp:Button ID="Button1" CssClass="btn-info" Text="Submit" />`

To work this asp button I have to put **runat="server"** in form tag like this

```
<form method="post" role="form" id="register-form" onload="Page_Load" autocomplete="off" runat="server">
```

Then I got error in Visual Studio

**'register-form' is not a valid identifier.**

**Edited Error is not displaying as before but validation still don't work I have used register_form**

And if I remove **id="register-form"** from form tag validation not working.

IMG of not Working validation

http:// imgur.com/a/ QoHP5

Here my validation java script file

http:// pastebin.com/yGGu2dYR

My html/aspx file

http:// pastebin.com/i0ewCGrz

**Update** :
It's not working if I change **register-form** to **register_form** in both html and java-script I run it without using **runat**

Comment: Look at the source code of the page in the browser ... what ID does the form element have

Comment: change the value `register-form` from form id like`register_form` and JS or wherever is used and it will work for sure

Comment: id="ctl00" in source code I don't understand what's that @JaromandaX

Comment: did'nt display any error like before but validation still didn't work ..! @PranavPatel

Comment: I'm surprised it's only ctl00 ... usually ASP mangles ID's together with the original ID in your code - maybe it's the '-' in the original ID that stops it from using the original. Anyway, it's an ASP thing ... I believe there's a way to prevent it, some configuration or other

Comment: Only combinations of alphanumeric characters and the underscore character ( _ ) are valid values for this property. Including spaces or other invalid characters will cause an ASP.NET page parser error.
Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.id.aspx

Comment: see [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/497802/how-to-stop-asp-net-from-changing-ids-in-order-to-use-jquery) for possible solutions

Comment: You need to decide if you want your form to be server side or not (`runat`). If not, then dump the server control `<asp:button` and do your client side validation and processing  that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change code like bellow to validation to work:

Html change and add class to form

```
<form method="post" role="form" class="register_form" id="register_form" onload="Page_Load" autocomplete="off" runat="server">
```

And In validation javascript file
Change from id selection

```
$("#register-form")
```

To class selection

```
$(".register_form")
```

After these step your validation will work fine with form with `runat="server"`

Comment: Not error but displaying in message box **Validation (XHTML5): Attribute 'clientidmode' is not a valid attribute of element 'form'** & validation didn't work

Comment: In this case need to add class in form and validate accordingly. You can check updated answer.