# Open modal on gridview row click

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a user control that has a `GridView` and when a user clicks on a row in this `GridView` the function `OnSelectedIndexChanged` is called, I'd like a modal to pop up after this occurs. I used the `ScriptManager` to invoke the script `$('#seasonInfoModal').modal()` which works in opening modals. The problem is it doesn't work when opening a modal which is defined within the same user control. The modal opens when it is inside the `page.aspx` , but doesn't open when inside the control `.ascx`. I have everything hooked up properly and have omitted some details. Here's what the overall code looks like

## main page.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" ... %>
<%@ Register Src="~/Controls/MyControl.ascx" TagPrefix="ACT" TagName="GeneralADM" %>

<ACT:GeneralADM runat="server"" />
```

## MyControl.ascx

```
<%@ Language="C#" AutoWireUP="true" Codebehind="" Inherits="" %>

<div runat="server">

     <!-- Seasonal Info-->
     <div runat="server" id="seasonInfoModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" draggable="true">
     </div>
     <!-- End seasonal info-->

     <!-- Start of Season Edit Modal -->
     <div id="seasonEditInfo" class="modal fade" role="dialog" draggable="false">
     </div>
     <!-- End of Season Edit Modal -->

      <asp:GridView>
      </asp:GridView>

</div>
```

In the code behind I try to open the modal like this

## MyControl.ascx.cs

```
protected void OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, GridViewEventArgs e){
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, 
      this.GetType(), 
      "seasonInfoModal", 
      "$('#seasonInfoModal').modal();", 
      true);
}
```

## issue

`#seasonInfoModal` doesn't popup instead a new modal is made with nothing inside it and the screen fades to dark on click. When I pull the `#seasonInfoModal` out of the control into the page where I am inserting the control itself, the modal actually pops up.

## question

How can I open the modal `#seasonInfoModal` when it is inside the control from that control's codebehind specifically from inside `OnSelectedIndexChanged` function?

Comment: Do you really *need* to open the popup from the server side? Do you really need the UpdatePanel? They just make a mess of things.

Comment: @mason I need to figure out how to open a modal inside of a user control.

Comment: The question is not providing any kind of information that what modal dialog is being used, no details about the event in which the modal is being tried to open.

Comment: @kaushalparik27 the event in which the modal is being opened is on a gridview click inside of a control. The problem is that ScriptManager doesn't open the #seasonInfoModal instead it creates a new one because it can't find #seasonInfoModal. So how can I open #seasonInfoModal from codeBehind of control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem may be caused by the [ID mangling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497802/how-to-stop-asp-net-from-changing-ids-in-order-to-use-jquery) performed by ASP.NET. Since the modal div is a server control (as specified by `runat="server"`), its ID in the rendered HTML is not `seasonInfoModal` but something like `MyControl1_seasonInfoModal`. As a result, the Javascript selector `$('#seasonInfoModal')` cannot find it.

You can change the startup script code, and pass the value of `seasonInfoModal.ClientID` to the jQuery selector, to account for the ID mangling:

```
protected void OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, GridViewEventArgs e){
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, 
      this.GetType(), 
      "seasonInfoModal", 
      string.Format("$('#{0}').modal();", seasonInfoModal.ClientID),
      true);
}
```

---

Other alternatives to avoid ID mangling would be:

1. To remove the `runat="server"` attribute if you don't need to access the div control in code-behind
2. To add `clientidmode="static"` to the div.
3. To use a class name (with the corresponding jQuery class selector) instead of an ID for the modal div.

These 3 solutions, however, would not behave correctly if several instances of the user control are present in the form. The modal of the first instance would always be used, and in cases 1 and 2, several controls of the form would have the same ID.

Comment: Just wondering. would adding the clientidmode="static" attribute to element achieve the same action? 
`<!-- Seasonal Info-->
     <div runat="server" id="seasonInfoModal" clientidmode="static" class="modal fade" role="dialog" draggable="true">
     </div>
     <!-- End seasonal info-->`

Comment: @LuisEstevez - It would have the same problem as my last two suggestions, but it would also work. I will add it to the list of "alternatives". Thanks. (I did not mention it because, for some reason, intellisense did not seem to know it for server div controls in my VS editor).